# How can I merge branches on github

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I use GitHub and also gerrithub.io. Gerrithub pushes commits into github repository. All worked fine until one moment.

Some day I edited `readme.md` in github and that made a new commit in master. After that, I push two commits in gerrithub and that's all.
Now I have last commit in branch master is that one in which I change `readme.md`. All commits from gerrithub is available, but seems like they are not in any branch.

So, is any way to pick all commits in master branch?

Comment: You mean your commit from gerrithub not available in github master branch?

Comment: Yes. All commits from gerrithub not in master branch, not in other brunches, but opens from link in gerrithub.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I change remote repository in git and now using only github.